# Scala _* to select a list of dataframe columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and a list of columns like this:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"))).toDF("language","users_count") 
val data_columns = List("language","users_count").map(x=>col(s"$x"))
```

Why does this work:

```
 df.select(data_columns:_ *).show()
```

But not this?

```
 df.select($"language", data_columns:_*).show()
```

Gives the error:

```
 error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
    (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
```

And how do I get it to work so I can use _* to select all columns in a list, but I also want to specify some other columns in the select?

Thanks!

**Update:**

based on @chinayangyangyong answer below, this is how I solved it:

```
df.select( $"language" +: data_columns :_*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there is no method on `Dataframe` with the signature `select(col: Column, cols: Column*): DataFrame`, but there is one with the signature `select(col: Column*): DataFrame`, which is why your first example works.

Interestingly, your second example would work if you were using `String` to select the columns since there is a method `select(col: String, cols: String*): DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.select(data_columns.head, data_columns.tail:_*),show()
```